# Apply hover cursor style to element or its :hover

Tags: css, hover

I have no problem with anything, I was just curious, what is better to use, when you want to change cursor while hovering. What would you prefer?

Method 1:

```
.element {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Method 2:

```
.element:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Both will do same - change your cursor to pointer when you hover `.element`. But, is there any difference between these 2 methods? Will it have any effect on browser (ie. performance) when using method 1 instead of method 2? I'm just curious.

Comment: Technically, there might be an ultra-tiny performance impact in browser parsing the DOM - being `.element:hover` a more specific selector than `.element` but realistically nothing that could ever be noticeable

Comment: In general, I would only use the `:hover` statement for things that will actually **change** on hover. Thus the first option should be preferred as it is the defualt state, (Oh..and it's shorter).

Answer (score 2):

There's no real difference. I would tend to put the style in where it looks best stylistically. It makes sense in the following example to have `cursor:pointer` in the `:hover` part as `.clickable` is only differently styled (i.e. has a blue background) on hover. Otherwise, I'd suggest having it in the regular `.clickable` selector.

HTML:

```
<span class="green-bg">Span 1</span>
<span class="green-bg clickable">Span 2</span>
<span class="green-bg">Span 3</span>
```

CSS:

```
.green-bg {
    background: green;
}
.clickable:hover {
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```